# HQL query with mapped entities

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, hql

```
@Entity(name = "locations")
@Table(name="locations")
public class Location {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="id") 
 private long id;

 @Column(name="name") 
 @NotEmpty(message="El Nombre es obligatorio") @Size(min=3, max=150, message="El Nombre debe tener entre 3 y 150 caracteres")
 private String name;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="location")
 private List<SportEvent> sportevents;

 }

@Entity(name = "sports")
@Table(name = "sports")
public class Sport {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="id") 
 private long id;

 @Column(name="name") 
 @NotEmpty(message="El Nombre es obligatorio") @Size(min=3, max=150, message="El Nombre debe tener entre 3 y 150 caracteres")
 private String name; 

 @Column(name="active")
 private Boolean active;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="sport") //nombre de la varible de la otra entidad
 private Set<SportEvent> sportevents;

}


@Entity(name = "sport_events")
@Table(name="sport_events")
public class SportEvent {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="id") 
 private long id;

 @Column(name="name") 
 @NotEmpty(message="El Nombre es obligatorio") @Size(min=3, max=150, message="El Nombre debe tener entre 3 y 150 caracteres")
 private String name; 

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="sport_id")
 private Sport sport;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="location_id")
 private Location location;

 }
```

The query:

```
 locations = (List<Location>) s.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT l " +
                                           "FROM locations l " +
                                           "JOIN l.sportevents AS lse " +
                                           "WHERE lse.sport.id = :id")
                                           .setLong("id", sportId)
                                           .list();
```

I want to get your respetivos locations for sporting events filtered by sport menu
With the following query I get are the locations for sporting events but ignore the condition WHERE id sport.

If it is properly mapped to access locations already have sporting events, I just need to do the JOIN condition sport but does not work.

At the hearing I print well:

```
<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
    <li>
        <label class="tree-toggle nav-header"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i><a href="#">${location.name}</a></label>
        <ul class="nav nav-list tree hide">
            <c:forEach var="sportevent" items="${location.sportevents}">
                <li><a href="#">${sportevent.name}</a></li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
</c:forEach>
```

In my database I have:

sports:
id-name
1-sport1
2-sport2
3-sport3

locations
id-name
1-location1
2-location2

Events
id-name-sport_id-location_id
1-event1-2-1
2-event2-2-1
3-event3-1-2
4-event4-1-2
5-event5-3-1
6-event6-3-1

Add locations to their respective events but belonging to a particular sport. With the current query I get only events by location. In my web I'm in the menu for the selected sport and I want to locations that have events for sport.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you try to rephrase your question? I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: Can you try to print the sql in to the console and paste it here, I see something wrong with the query, i think you cannot use lse.sport as lse is a collection in this case.